# Datastream `POSTGRES_PUBLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST`

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, google-datastream

When I tried to create Data stream with Terraform according to the Google Cloud official blog[1], then I got the following error.

> Enter a value: yes
>
> module.test-db.google_datastream_stream.stream: Creating...
> module.test-db.google_datastream_stream.stream: Still creating... [10s
> elapsed] ╷ │ Error: Error waiting to create Stream: Error waiting for
> Creating Stream:
> {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","domain":"datastream.googleapis.com","metadata":{"message":"Some
> validations failed to complete successfully, see the full list in the
> operation
> metadata.","originalMessage":"","time":"2023-07-22T05:49:41Z","uuid":"8d5f7de0-2853-11ee-95df-fe87037b833d"},"reason":"VALIDATION_FAILURE"}
> │ {"code":"POSTGRES_VALIDATE_PUBLICATION","description":"Validates
> that the publication exists and configured for the required
> tables.","message":[{"code":"POSTGRES_PUBLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST","level":"ERROR","message":"Datastream
> failed to find the publication. Make sure that the publication exists
> and that Datastream has the necessary permissions to access
> it.","metadata":{"publication_name":"datastream_publication"}}],"state":"FAILED"}
> │  │  │  │   with module.test-db.google_datastream_stream.stream, │
> on ../../modules/db/main.tf line 82, in resource
> "google_datastream_stream" "stream": │   82: resource
> "google_datastream_stream" "stream" {

But I already create the publication according to the official documentation[2].
Instead, I also tried to create it from GCP's console. But I got the same error. Could you point out the problem or missing things?

- terraform file for first apply

```
# See versions at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#database_version
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance" {
  name             = "test-instance"
  region           = var.region
  database_version = "POSTGRES_15"
  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
    database_flags {
      name  = "cloudsql.logical_decoding"
      value = "on"
    }
    ip_configuration {

            // Datastream IPs will vary by region. These are for Tokyo regions. https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/ip-allowlists-and-regions
            authorized_networks {
                value = "34.146.177.122"
            }

            authorized_networks {
                value = "35.189.147.253"
            }

            authorized_networks {
                value = "35.194.107.163"
            }

            authorized_networks {
                value = "34.84.33.5"
            }

            authorized_networks {
                value = "34.146.175.7"
            }

            authorized_networks {
                value = "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
        }
  }
  deletion_protection = "false"
}

resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  name     = "test-db"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance.name
}

resource "google_sql_user" "user" {
  name     = var.user_name
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance.name
  host     = ""
  password = var.password
}

resource "google_datastream_connection_profile" "source" {
   display_name          = "Postgresql Source"
   location = var.region
   connection_profile_id = "source"
   postgresql_profile {
       hostname = google_sql_database_instance.instance.public_ip_address
       username = google_sql_user.user.name
       password = google_sql_user.user.password
       database = google_sql_database.database.name
   }
}

resource "google_datastream_connection_profile" "destination" {
   display_name          = "BigQuery Destination"
   location = var.region
   connection_profile_id = "destination"
   bigquery_profile {
    
   }
}
```

- terraform file that should be applied after setting up DB according to [2]

```
resource "google_datastream_stream" "stream" {
   display_name  = "Postgres to BigQuery Stream"
   location      = var.region
   stream_id     = "stream"
   desired_state = "RUNNING"
   source_config {
       source_connection_profile = google_datastream_connection_profile.source.id
       postgresql_source_config {
        publication      = "datastream_publication"
        replication_slot = "datastream_replication_slot"
        }
   }
   destination_config {
       destination_connection_profile = google_datastream_connection_profile.destination.id
       bigquery_destination_config {
           data_freshness = "900s"
           source_hierarchy_datasets {
               dataset_template {
                   location = var.region
               }
           }
       }
   }
   backfill_all {}
}
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/replicating-postgres-data-to-bigquery?hl=en
[2] https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/configure-your-source-postgresql-database#cloudsqlforpostgres-create-publication-and-replication-slot